# using JPA 2.0 on hibernate 5 when deploy to websphere

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, websphere

when I try to deploy my application on Websphere Application Server 9.0 I got this error

```
An error occurred in the org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider persistence provider when it attempted to create the container entity manager factory for the ApplicationEntityManager persistence unit. The following error occurred: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider incompatible with javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
```

and someone suggests me to downgrade my JPA to 2.0. is this possible to use JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 5.2.1. or there is another solution to solve my problem.

Comment: Yes JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 5.2.1  is possible to use, There might be some configuration issue with your application, You can take help from here .https://www.boraji.com/hibernate-5-jpa-2-configuration-example

Comment: That link uses JPA 2.1, not 2.0

Answer (score 1):

If using WebSphere Application Server traditional,
here are the instructions to set the JPA spec level provided by the server,
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tejb_idmod_jpaspec.html

That said, Hibernate 5.2.1 appears to have a dependency on JPA 2.1, not 2.0.  See the dependencies indicated here,
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.1.Final

The issue might be caused by including a copy of the JPA spec JARs within the application such that the server and the application are trying to load different copies of the same class which collide and produce this error.  Check your application and remove all copies of the JPA spec JAR from it (including any supplied by Hibernate), such that the server copy alone is always used to load JPA.

Comment: can I just exclude all server JPA, and just use application JARs?